# Do we have Pre Install script like Post Install?

Tags: appexchange, service-cloud-console, postinstall, install

We have a app in appexchange and would like to know if there is a Pre Install script similar to post install script?

The reason is our application is applicable only to organizations which have console enabled otherwise it will fail. When user tries to install the app, we would like to warn the user "that installation cannot proceed as the console is not enabled"

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3):

Not per se. The ways you could achieve something like this are:

- use the options in package upload to indicate which features customers must have installed, so they can get warned if they don't have those. This is obviously only usable for the features included in that list, and I am not sure that console is one of those.
- have a "mini-package" that customers install first, which only has a post-install script which checks compatibility. Seems like overkill.
- just document it really well as part of the installation process in big letters. Probably the option I would go for.